# Disable Gridview Row

Tags: asp.net, gridview, row

The problem I am having is in a gridview I have multiple buttons and some dropdowns. Anytime the buttons or dropdowns are acted upon, I need either the entire row to be disabled until the postback completes, or all the items in the row to be disabled until the postback is complete. The reason for this is that anytime there are multiple clicks or, essentially, multiple postbacks trying to occur, my page freezes up and requires a refresh. I'm really not even sure where to start so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The application we are using is kinda old and we dont have jQuery. I talked to my team lead about it and he says we can try it but it would have to get approved from the higher ups and that may take a while. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) to disable the button on submit:

```
$('form').submit(function(){  
      $(':submit', this).click(function() {  
         return false;  
     });  
 });
```

You could also use the `jQuery` plugin [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos) which prevents that you can click anything then.

Comment: Yes, we ended up getting jQuery and this was certainly the fix, thank you!